# ora-30926 when using two primary keys

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm getting the following error

> ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

when attempting to execute the following statement:

```
  MERGE INTO new_table nt
    USING ( select c.id, 
                   cd.evaluation_date, cd.population_total_count, cd.population_urban_count, cd.population_birth_rate_per1k,
                   cf.gdp_total_dollars, cf.gdp_per_capita_dollars
            from countries c, country_demographics cd, country_financials cf 
            where c.id = cd.country_id
            and   cd.evaluation_date = cf.evaluation_date
            and   cd.country_id = cf.country_id 
            order by c.id ) rec
    ON ( rec.id = nt.country_id )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
      UPDATE SET --nt.country_id             = rec.id,
                 nt.evaluation_date        = rec.evaluation_date,
                 nt.population_total_count = rec.population_total_count,
                 nt.population_urban_count = rec.population_urban_count,
                 nt.population_birth_rate_per1k  = rec.population_birth_rate_per1k,
                 nt.gdp_total_dollars      = rec.gdp_total_dollars,
                 nt.gdp_per_capita_dollars = rec.gdp_per_capita_dollars
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (country_id, evaluation_date, population_total_count, population_urban_count, population_birth_rate_per1k,
                  gdp_total_dollars, gdp_per_capita_dollars)
      VALUES (rec.id, rec.evaluation_date, rec.population_total_count, rec.population_urban_count, rec.population_birth_rate_per1k,
                  rec.gdp_total_dollars, rec.gdp_per_capita_dollars);
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that both country_id and evaluation_date are primary keys in my new_table.  I currently have the country_id commented in the update statement because that was giving me ora-38104.

> ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated:
>   "NT"."COUNTRY_ID"

any idea how to handle dual keys in this situation?  that is, if that is even what is wrong.

EDIT: select statement runs fine by itself.  For example, here's what that query returns:
[image: sample data from select statement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the SELECT in the USING clause is returning duplicate values in the id column (used in the ON clause).  Run it by itself and sort on the id column to find out. Columns in the ON clause are the key values and by definition cannot be updated and must be unique.

EDIT: If you have a composite primary key, then all primary key columns need to be in the ON clause and NOT in the update:

```
MERGE INTO new_table nt
    USING ( select c.id, 
                   cd.evaluation_date, cd.population_total_count, cd.population_urban_count, cd.population_birth_rate_per1k,
                   cf.gdp_total_dollars, cf.gdp_per_capita_dollars
            from countries c, country_demographics cd, country_financials cf 
            where c.id = cd.country_id
            and   cd.evaluation_date = cf.evaluation_date
            and   cd.country_id = cf.country_id 
            order by c.id ) rec
    ON ( rec.id = nt.country_id AND rec.evaluation_date = nt.evaluation_date )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
      UPDATE SET nt.population_total_count = rec.population_total_count,
                 nt.population_urban_count = rec.population_urban_count,
                 nt.population_birth_rate_per1k  = rec.population_birth_rate_per1k,
                 nt.gdp_total_dollars      = rec.gdp_total_dollars,
                 nt.gdp_per_capita_dollars = rec.gdp_per_capita_dollars
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (country_id, evaluation_date, population_total_count, population_urban_count, population_birth_rate_per1k,
                  gdp_total_dollars, gdp_per_capita_dollars)
      VALUES (rec.id, rec.evaluation_date, rec.population_total_count, rec.population_urban_count, rec.population_birth_rate_per1k,
                  rec.gdp_total_dollars, rec.gdp_per_capita_dollars);
```

Comment: select statement runs fine by itself.  There are 11 rows with ID:1 for example.  the second key is the date that gives each row a unique date per id.

Comment: yes, those 11 ID's of 1 are your duplicates.  See amended example now that I know you have a composite primary key.

Comment: that worked.  the only difference is I had to use AND instead of a comma in the ON statement:
ON ( rec.id = nt.country_id AND rec.evaluation_date = nt.evaluation_date )